# jQuery script for Bootstrap's carousel does not work

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am following an online course, but some piece of code from there is not working for me as it is expected.

What I am trying to do: change the interval of the Bootstrap's carousel and add 2 buttons (one stopping the carousel and one making the carousel slide again).

The behaviour I get instead:

1. in Chrome 68.0, the stop button only works if it is hovered. As soon as I remove the mouse from the button, the carousel starts moving again as if I pressed "play" button.
2. in Firefox 68.0, scripts have no effects at all. The buttons do not work, and the interval of the carousel is not changed.

This is the part of the html that contains the carousel:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-content">
        <div class="col">
            <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/uthappizza.png" alt="uthappizza">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <h2>Uthappizza <span class="badge badge-danger">HOT</span> <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">$4.99</span></h2>
                            <p class="d-none d-sm-block">A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/buffet.png" alt="buffet">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <h2>Weekend Grand Buffet <span class="badge badge-danger">NEW</span></h2>
                            <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of five different salads, six enticing appetizers, six main entrees and five choicest desserts. Free flowing bubbly and soft drinks. All for just $19.99 per person </p>            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/alberto.png" alt="alberto">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <h2>Alberto Somayya</h2>
                            <h4>Executive Chef</h4>
                            <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Award winning three-star Michelin chef with wide International experience having worked closely with whos-who in the culinary world, he specializes in creating mouthwatering Indo-Italian fusion experiences. </p>                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="btn-group" id="carouselButton">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="carousel-pause">
                            <span class="fa fa-pause"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="carousel-play">
                            <span class="fa fa-play"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the part of the html document that loads the scripts:

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mycarousel").carousel({ interval: 2000 });
        $("#carousel-pause").click(function() {
            $("$mycarousel").carousel('pause');
        });
        $("#carousel-play").click(function() {
            $("#mycarousel").carousel('cycle');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Part of css that brings the "play"/"stop" buttons forward (so they are not accidentally hidden under the carousel):

```
#carouselButton {
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 1500;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be help you

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
    <img src="assets/img/backgrounds/1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="img1">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Carousel Template with Bootstrap 4</h1>
        <div class="description">
            <p> 
                Click on the buttons below to stop / start the autoplay:
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="pause-cycle-buttons">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-customized btn-cycle disabled">
                <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-customized btn-pause">
                <i class="fas fa-pause"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

/*
    Stop / Start carousel autoplay
*/

$('.btn-customized').on('click', function(){

    if( ! $(this).hasClass('disabled') ) {

        if( $(this).hasClass('btn-pause') ) {
            $('.carousel').carousel('pause');
        }
        else {
            $('.carousel').carousel('cycle');
        }

        $('.btn-pause, .btn-cycle').toggleClass('disabled');
        $(this).blur();

    }

});
```

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mycarousel").carousel({ interval: 10 });
  $("#carousel-pause").click(function() {
    $("#mycarousel").carousel('pause');
  });
  $("#carousel-play").click(function() {
    $("#mycarousel").carousel('cycle');
  });
});
```

```css
#carouselButton {
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 1500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-content">
      <div class="col">
        <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/14/23/12/nature-3082832_960_720.jpg" alt="uthappizza">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h2>Uthappizza <span class="badge badge-danger">HOT</span> <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">$4.99</span></h2>
                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/14/23/12/nature-3082832_960_720.jpg" alt="buffet">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h2>Weekend Grand Buffet <span class="badge badge-danger">NEW</span></h2>
                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of five different salads, six enticing appetizers, six main entrees and five choicest desserts. Free flowing bubbly and soft drinks. All for just $19.99 per person </p>            
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/14/23/12/nature-3082832_960_720.jpg" alt="alberto">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h2>Alberto Somayya</h2>
                <h4>Executive Chef</h4>
                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Award winning three-star Michelin chef with wide International experience having worked closely with whos-who in the culinary world, he specializes in creating mouthwatering Indo-Italian fusion experiences. </p>                        
              </div>
            </div>
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
            </a>
            <div class="btn-group" id="carouselButton">
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="carousel-pause">
                <span class="fa fa-pause">Pause</span>
              </button>
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="carousel-play">
                <span class="fa fa-play">Play</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Try not using slim version of jQuery, instead use minified version as it works better. I faced problems for using that version.